# JSP Exception, not able to access absolute URL

Tags: jsp

I am getting jsp Exception. When exception occurs, page content is not getting loaded and code which is causing this exception is in div section **new-product-promo**.

Please suggest what is wrong with this URL. Is there any other way to handle this exception in jsp page?

```
<%@  page language="java" contentType="text/html" session ="false" %>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function closeWarningMessage() {  

      for (var i=0; i<document.forms.length; i++) { 
        document.forms[i].reset(); 
      }        
    }     
  </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="closeWarningMessage();">  // page loaded till here
  <jsp:include flush="true" page="/myCart/logoutHeader.jsp"/>
  <div id="new-product-promo">
    <c:if test="${ !empty product.newPromo}">
      <c:import url="http://www.mStore.com ${product.newPromo}" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    </c:if>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL looks wrong to me: you have a space in it. Souldn't it be something like

```
http://www.mStore.com/${product.newPromo}
```

?

Anyway, you could wrap this inside a `<c:catch>` or, even better, get the contents of this URL from a servlet/action before dispatching to the JSP (or to another JSP if it's not possible to load the external URL).

Comment: ,Thanks for your input. actually the dynamic URL starts with /com/....  so the reesulting URL is right. i have used <c:catch> to put that url. now its working fine. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're missing `/` in your import:

```
<c:import url="http://www.mStore.com/${product.newPromo}" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```